# The plus sign is deleted when importing to the xls file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel

Laravel version 5.4

Expected behaviour
[image]

Actual behaviour
[image]
Steps to reproduce the behaviour

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
                    'A' => '@'
                ));
                foreach ($order_details as $key => $detail) {
                 $sheet->appendRow([(string)$detail->model->id_supplier, $detail->model->mintitle, $detail->qty, $detail->price, $detail->qty * $detail->price,]);
                 $sheet->setHeight($sheet->getHighestRow(), 45);
                }
```

How to import a number with a plus sign?

Comment: try appending `'` before the number. E.g., `'+4`, it will be treated as a string though. Excel things. lol xD

Comment: Where you do want's do add a "plus sign" ? you can use it like this $detail->model->id_supplier.'+'. you need to use concatenation to append a string.

Comment: Data from + I get from the database. + always before the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that is microsoft excel, or some similar app; then it is not in your code, excel treats the +digit as a positive digit, and hence it removes the +, happens with the zeroes as well, try to include '' wrapper around your value to convert it to string and to prevent excel from doing so.

Comment: If you wrap it, how do you hide it then?
The value must not be wrapped when copying. Further there is an insertion in an MsAccess, and there data validation.

Comment: if you would shed more light on the situation and why you need the + sign, i might be a better help .. you can try first to send it as a (string) by casting which you did in the supplier_id, but that is not going to be helpful in case you wanted to transfer the data to MsAccess, in case you wanted only to show the + sign while maintaining it as integer/double .. i believe there is an option in excel to "format cells" as to  change how the data is displayed ..

Comment: i believe the code for that as follows .. alter it as it suits you : `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('+#,##0.00');` [PHPExcel](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ouardisoft/PHPExcel/class-PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html)

Comment: Managers from this table copy the data and insert it into the MsAccess. And in the MsAccess itself there is a comparison of data on id_supplier. this is the code of suppliers in general, and one of the vendors has all the codes with +, but there are also suppliers without signs.

Comment: it's a money format, and I can have an id_supplier + 15235d

Comment: still a little unclear on what you are trying to achieve, you want the cell to display + while maintaining its type as integer/double? or are you trying to unify the data so you can maintain the results without hidden miscalculations? .. if you can tell what you: 1- what data type you are sending? 2- what data type you want to display and save in excel?

Comment: I send the string and want to display it as a string, but the program itself conventionally converts a string (+121345) into a number and removes +.

Comment: you can change the format as you like .. instead of #,##00.00 which displays 1,1234.00 .. you can choose +0 which will display +11234 .. but also will display -+5564 for -5,564.00 ..

Comment: As I understand it, the ability to display the + sign with numbers does not work. as a string

Comment: no .. ignore that comment .. i was replying to your previous one .. what you need is to change the cells type to text instead of general .. here is the protion you need `->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT)` whatever you send it is going to be a string in the cell. even if you copy paste it in excel it is going to be a string.(assuming you maintain the cell type while copying)

Comment: full code `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT)`

Comment: Sorry just did not understand you. Wrapped the variable in " and the data began to be displayed with a plus and inserted into the MsAccess.  (string)"\"".$detail->model->id_supplier."\""

Comment: in the excel truth does not look nice

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the number you expect was a positive digit(+49983), if you reproduce the number with + sign, it removes + sign while displaying in excel.,

To check open a new excel and try to add +49983 and move to next column, the + will automatically gone, because of the positive digit.